# Generating new tuples via a rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I'm trying to go through the distinct arrangements of n integers, and generate a new one for each based on the following rule:

e.g. Looking at the permutations of (1,2,3): (2,3,1) would generate (3,1,2) since the index of 2 in the first tuple is 1 so 2 replaces 1, index of 3 is 2 so 3 replaces 2, index of 1 is 3 so 1 replaces 3

I was wondering what the most efficient way would be to do this?

I've already started the function using the permutations function from itertools:

```
# Define a function with the input of a list of the permutations/n-tuples L e.g. [1,2,3]

from itertools import *
def GeneratePerm(L):
  perm=list(permutations(L))
  for p in perm:
      for element in p:
          index=p.index(element)
          index=index+1
          if element==index:
              new_tup=p.index(element)
          print('new_tup:',new_tup)
```

I'm really not sure where to go from here so any responses would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Thanks for your quick reply! I'm not so sure though because if you take (1,2,3), it generates (1,2,3) rather than (2,3,1)

Comment: What if you have `(1, 2, 4)`? The index of 4 is 3 (or 2 strictly speaking) but there is no 3.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I'm only looking at tuples of consecutive integers starting from 1, so (1,2,3), (1,2,3,4) etc.

Comment: Use a list to map each number to its index. Alternatively use sorting for an elegant one-liner, although this is less efficient (time complexity wise: O(n log n) vs O(n)).

Comment: I haven't tested this extensively, but I think `operator.itemgetter(*(x-1 for x in t))(t)` does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Python is zero-based in its indices for tuple, it would be simpler for you to consider permutations of `(0, 1, 2)`, which is common, rather than the permutation of `(1, 2, 3)`. It would also be simpler to use lists rather than tuples for this problem. But here is some code that will find the one-based "inverse permutation" for a given one-based permutation.

```
p_example = (2, 3, 1)  # to (3, 1, 2)

def inv_1_based_permutation(p):
    result = [0] * len(p)
    for ndx, val in enumerate(p):
        result[val - 1] = ndx + 1
    return tuple(result)

print(inv_1_based_permutation(p_example))
```

Note that the `- 1` and `+ 1` are due to the permutations being one-based, and the final line in the routine converts from a list to a tuple. The intermediate list is necessary since the algorithm works by modifying a sequence in an order that is different from that used in the result (the order is based on the input parameter). The time complexity of this routine is `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the permutation. Your code is `O(n^2)` since `index()` is `O(n)` and you call that once for each member of the permutation.

Comment: @MathsicalStudies: Not so brilliant--this is the standard way to find the inverse of a permutation that is given in that format (though they are usually zero-based). But you are very welcome!